# I'm trying to achieve scroll snap, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, haskell-snap-framework

I'm trying to achieve scroll snap using CSS.
Splash, page1, page2 is how I want my HTML to snap.
My CSS doesn't seem to snap, what am I doing wrong?

```css
body{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.splash{
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.page1{
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.page2{
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="splash"></section>
  <section class="page1"></section>
  <section class="page2"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: I believe you need to add a parent div with the scroll-snap-type property set. See this example and use it to structure your layout https://codepen.io/fraggley/pen/xxwjBdG

Answer (score 1):

You are close, the only thing you have to add is a wrapping container with full height of the view-port and also set each section to full height of the view-port:

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.page1{
  background-color: red
}

.splash {
  background-color: green
}
.page2 {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="splash">splash</section>
    <section class="page1">page1</section>
    <section class="page2">page2</section>
  </div>
</body>
```